# Add / Remove to Array using Hooks (useState)

Tags: arrays, react-native, state, react-hooks, mobile-application

I am trying to create a Bingo Game in React-Native. Each button in the Bingo Grid is a TouchableOpacity with an integer ID. My idea was to have the button being pressed either added to an array or removed from an array, depending on whether or not it was selected for the bingo game (using color of the button).

As of right now, when I open the app and click a button once (marking it as selected), console logs an empty array. When I click it again (deselecting it), the console logs the ID of that button. This happens separately with all the buttons when I click on them rather than collectively all referring to one array.

My code now:

```
const sol1 = ['1', '5', '21', '25'];

const [color, setColor] = useState('white');
const [marked, setMarked] = useState([]);
const addButton = (tapID) => setMarked(marked => [...marked, tapID]);
const removeButton = (tapID) => {
    let name = tapID;
    setMarked(marked.filter((tapID)=>(tapID !== name)))
};

const checkWin = () => {
    if (marked.length === null) {
        console.log("nothing");
    } else {
        var containsAll = sol1.every(i => marked.includes(i));
        if (containsAll  === true){
            console.log("win");
        }
        console.log("WOAH");
    }
}

const markPlay = () => {
    if (color === 'white'){
        setColor('#b8b8ab');
        addButton(tapID);
        console.log(marked);
        checkWin()
    } else {
        setColor('white');
        removeButton(tapID);
        console.log(marked);
        checkWin()
    }
}
```

This is what the output looks like when I select all 4 corners then deselect them.

```
 LOG  WOAH
 LOG  []
 LOG  WOAH
 LOG  []
 LOG  WOAH
 LOG  []
 LOG  WOAH
 LOG  []
 LOG  WOAH
 LOG  ["1"]
 LOG  WOAH
 LOG  ["5"]
 LOG  WOAH
 LOG  ["21"]
 LOG  WOAH
 LOG  ["25"]
 LOG  WOAH
```

Instead, I want it to just show one array that fills with ["1","5","21","25"], and then notifies of a win.

Any help/guidance is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Updating the state variables is not done right-away which means when you call the `addButton` to add a mark in your `marked` array it is not done right away, hence you see this empty array on next `console.log`.

You need to bind this condition check (`checkWin`) inside a `useEffect` which will have its dependency on your array `marked`.

Something like this..

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(marked);
    checkWin()
}, [marked])


const markPlay = () => {
    if (color === 'white'){
        setColor('#b8b8ab');
        addButton(tapID);
    } else {
        setColor('white');
        removeButton(tapID);
    }
}
```